# How to search Google from iPhone Spotlight

Tags: iphone, search

When I go to search, it says, "Search iPhone" in the box.

How do I change that to search Google?

Comment: OK, reading from the answer, I think I understand, now. First of all **those are two different questions**. Please ask another one for the email notification, there are ways and I'll gladly explain them on the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type in the item you want to search for, an option will appear "Search Web".  Press this and it will do a Google Search for the item you entered.

You cannot change the text itself (but the above should suffice in terms of searching google for a search term).

Matthew's answer above re the mail notifications is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider the excellent [Google Search](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-search/id284815942?mt=8) app.

Comment: since I deleted his bit on mail notification, you can strike that part too :p I suggest you edit your answer to only leave the Google Search app bit :)

Comment: @Loic Ok, taken care of.